# Sort php/mysql microstime

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, microtime

what is the shortest and most beautiful way to sort an microtime value, which is importet from a mysql database, with php that the latest date/time is on the top or the first value of an array.
Thanks

Comment: Three issues: 1. 'shortest' is a question to be determine by benchmarking. 2. 'most beautiful' is subjective and is therefore off-topic for this site. 3. Your question contains no code. Have you tried anything, or were you hoping we would deliver a fully-functional solution from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the SQL `ORDER BY` clause, essentially you do `SELECT .. FROM .. ORDER BY mycolumn` to do what you're looking to do.